# UIScrollView error in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am new to UIScrollView. I don't know how to add buttons with them. In my app, I need a button in horizontal view. But when I tried to create the UIScrollView programatically, its not working. It is throwing some errors. pls help me

I tried to implement this using storyboard too, but failed as  I dont how to connect them both using the viewDidLoad.

this is the code I have used so far:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.layerPosition = self.toplayer.frame.origin.x;

    UIScrollView *scrollview =[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
     scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=YES;
     scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
     scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(newView:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [button setTitle:@"Excavations",@"Concrete",@"Framing",@"Insulation" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

   [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
   scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,960);

}
```

if I am doing wrong pls tell me the correct procedure to do it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can see just one error in your code now:

`[button setTitle:@"Excavations",@"Concrete",@"Framing",@"Insulation" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

setTitle: expect just one string, try this:

```
[button setTitle:@"Excavations" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You probably want to add this button thou your scroll view so you need to call:

```
[scrollview addSubview:button];
```

It should help, if not post your error.

I assume you want to pass UIControlEventTouchUpInside instead UIControlEventTouchDown as a button control event.

Answer (score 0):

try this .it will work

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
          [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.layerPosition = self.toplayer.frame.origin.x;

        UIScrollView *scrollview =[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
         scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=YES;
         scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
         scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(newView:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [button setTitle:@"Excavations" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

       [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
       scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,960);

    }
```

Comment: scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; add this if you want to see where it is .